# what is [1:] using len function to find length?

Tags: python, python-3.7

In this code:

```
word='pardis'
print(len(word[1:]))
```

the output is 5. I also try this code for some other words and I find out that the output is length of word minus 1.
My question is what is [1:] meaning and what it does? I am unfamiliar with it. I guess It is the reason that output is length minus 1

Comment: You say you still don't know the answer. Did you visit the linked duplicate? You will find all the answers there.

Comment: yes I visited that and I didnt see anything like a[1:]

Comment: Really? The accepted answer has `a[start:]` what do you think that means? If you're still not sure, then the best thing to do is write some test code. Play with different slices (`[:]` is slice notation), and see what they do. It can be confusing at first, but it's really very simple.

Comment: Ok Thanks, maybe I should improve my English langue to understand better.

Comment: Good luck - enjoy your Python